# Corrupt file from File.renameTo()

Tags: java, android, itext

This is a followup to this question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847814/damaged-pdf-from-itext-in-android), involving iText. I create a new Pdf with a different rotation angle, then delete the old one and rename the new one to the name of the old one. I've determined that my problem actually happens (only when rotation == null, wtf) with the call to

```
outFile.renameTo(inFile)
```

Oddly enough renameTo() returns true, but the file is not equal to the original, outFile will no longer open in Adobe Reader on Windows. I tried analyzing the corrupted Pdf file in a desktop Pdf repair program, and the results I get are:

```
The end-of-file marker was not found.
The ‘startxref’ keyword or the xref position was not found.
The end-of-file marker was not found.
```

If I leave out the calls to delete() and renameTo() I am left with two files, neither of which are corrupt. I have also tried copying the file contents with a byte[] with the same results. I have tried outFile.renameTo(new File(inFile.toString()) since inFile is actually a subclass of File with the same results. I have tried new FileDescriptor().sync() with the same results. I have tried adding this broadcast in between every file operation with the same results:

```
PdfRotateService.appContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri
            .parse("file://")));
```

I have tried sleeping the Thread with the same results. I have verified the paths are correct. No exceptions are thrown and delele() and renameTo() return true. I have also tried keeping a reference to the FileOutputStream and manually closing it in the finally block.

I am beginning to think there is a bug in the Android OS or something (but maybe I am overlooking something simple), please help! I want a rotated Pdf with the same filename as the original.

```
static boolean rotatePdf(LocalFile inFile, int angle)
{
    PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfStamper stamper = null;

    LocalFile outFile = getGoodFile(inFile, ROTATE_SUFFIX);

    boolean worked = true;

    try
    {
        reader = new PdfReader(inFile.toString());
        stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(outFile));

        int i = FIRST_PAGE;
        int l = reader.getNumberOfPages();

        for (; i <= l; ++i)
        {
            int desiredRot = angle;
            PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(i);

            PdfNumber rotation = pageDict.getAsNumber(PdfName.ROTATE);

            if (rotation != null)
            {
                desiredRot += rotation.intValue();
                desiredRot %= 360;
            }
            // else
            // worked = false;

            pageDict.put(PdfName.ROTATE, new PdfNumber(desiredRot));
        }
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        worked = false;
        Log.w("Rotate", "Caught IOException in rotate");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (DocumentException e)
    {
        worked = false;
        Log.w("Rotate", "Caught DocumentException in rotate");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally
    {

        boolean z = closeQuietly(stamper);
        boolean y = closeQuietly(reader);

        if (!(y && z))
            worked = false;
    }

    if (worked)
    {
        if (!inFile.delete())
            worked = false;

        if (!outFile.renameTo(inFile))
            worked = false;
    }
    else
    {
        outFile.delete();
    }

    return worked;
}

static boolean closeQuietly(Object resource)
{
    try
    {
        if (resource != null)
        {
            if (resource instanceof PdfReader)
                ((PdfReader) resource).close();
            else if (resource instanceof PdfStamper)
                ((PdfStamper) resource).close();
            else
                ((Closeable) resource).close();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.w("Exception during Resource.close()", ex);
    }
    return false;
}

public static LocalFile getGoodFile(LocalFile inFile, String suffix)
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    String outString = inFile.getParent() + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR +
            removeExtension(inFile.getName()) + suffix + getExtension(inFile.getName());

    LocalFile outFile = new LocalFile(inFile.getParent() + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR +
            removeExtension(inFile.getName()) + suffix + getExtension(inFile.getName()));

    int n = 1;
    while (outFile.isFile())
    {
        outFile = new LocalFile(inFile.getParent() + DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR +
                removeExtension(inFile.getName()) + suffix + n + getExtension(inFile.getName()));
        ++n;
    }
    return outFile;
}
```

Comment: when you do `outFile.renameTo(inFile)` and `inFile` is currupt in the end you can be pretty sure that `outfile` was already corrupt. E.g. your `FileOutputStream` was not closed. `renameTo` uses system level renaming and that's kind of guaranteed to work.

Comment: But if I comment out the if/else block with the delete() and renameTo() methods, neither are corrupt?

Comment: Should also mention I have tried keeping a reference to the FileOutputStream and manually closing it in finally block...same results, no exceptions thrown

Comment: Hum, `new FileDescriptor().sync();` is nonsense, `out.flush(); out.getFD().sync();` is what you want (`out` is a `FileOutputStream`) after that close it. The next thing you can check is how the corrupt file differs from a correct file. E.g. using a hexeditor to compare the files with / without rename&delete.

Comment: Oh, `The end-of-file marker was not found.` would IMO mean you have not closed the output correctly before renaming it and it's missing some bytes at the end.

Comment: I tried manually flush, sync close the FileOutputStream but no joy. I don't think it works that way, PdfStamper is responsible for closing the stream. I guess the library doesn't close the stream properly in certain cases. When the files are left alone till operation is done, some automated system process closes the stream the rest of the way (?) I tried setting stamper to null and System.gc() no joy...also tried my best messing with the library, didn't get anywhere..any other suggestions??

Comment: Have you tried copying the outFile to inFile instead of renaming it? Might be worth a try in spite of an success making the situation weirder still...