# How can I simulate the device being disconnected as a media device?

Tags: android

I am having a problem with files being corrupted while being manipulated in my app. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870997/corrupt-file-from-file-renameto) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847814/damaged-pdf-from-itext-in-android). It appears as if the FileOutputStream is not being closed properly, but I am close to 100% certain at this point this problem is not my code or the library I am using. The stream is being flushed and closed properly.

I have managed to determine that the problem only happens when my phone is connected as a media device and sdcard is accessible to Windows (no exceptions are thrown and everything appears to have worked correctly but the output file is corrupt, missing a few bytes - end-of-file information). Turning off USB debugging does not fix it. Disconnecting the phone from the computer and then running the app fixes it.

My question is, how can I programmatically achieve the same fix?
I have tried:

```
this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED, Uri
                .parse("file://")));
```

and

```
this.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SHARED, Uri
                .parse("file://")));
```

which doesn't seem to have any affect, the file is still corrupt. I have Googled but am not finding what I need to do.

Failing that, what can I check to warn the user to disconnect the device first?

This particular device has no real removable sdcard, its an Htc One GPE.